# TikZ: How to extract / highlight a segment of a curved path

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-path

I would like to highlight a segment of a curvy path (color, thickness) defined by several controls as shown in the following image. I already tried it using intersections and clipping but I failed.

Preferably, I would like to mark the end points of the highlighted segment by arrows. The segment of the path which should be highlighted is given as an 'interval' of the original path, e.g. start highlighting after 1/3 of the original path and stop highlighting at 5/7 of the path.

But in fact, if I would have a solution if I define start and stop of the highlighted segment somehow by hand, I would be glad.

Any ideas?

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, >=stealth, ->]
    \tikzstyle{node_style}=[inner sep=2pt, circle, fill=black]

    \node[node_style, label=right:{$x$}] at (3,3) (x) {};
    \node[node_style, label=below:{$y$}] at (0,0) (y) {};

    \draw (y) .. controls ++(2,-0.1)  .. (1,1) .. controls ++(-1.5,1.5)  .. (2,2) .. controls ++(2,-0.3)  ..(x);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Choosing exactly 1/3 and 5/7 positions would be difficult, but you can utilize two intermediate points `(1,1)` and `(2,2)` and draw the same bezier curve between them with thick red line. Note also that I stretched the two ends by `2pt`s to compensate for the length of the arrow heads. You don't need to do this if you use the default arrows instead of `stealth`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, > = stealth]
    \tikzstyle{node_style}=[inner sep=2pt, circle, fill=black]

    \node[node_style, label=right:{$x$}] at (3,3) (x) {};
    \node[node_style, label=below:{$y$}] at (0,0) (y) {};

    \draw[->] (y.center)..controls ++(2,-0.1)..(1,1)..controls ++(-1.5,1.5)..(2,2)..controls ++(2,-0.3)..(x);
    \draw[red,very thick,<->,shorten >=-2pt,shorten <=-2pt] (1,1)..controls ++(-1.5,1.5)..(2,2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmmm...I suppose that OP wants to do that when the start and end points are not explicitly known along the path. For example, from one third of the full path to two thirds... Maybe with a decoration?

Comment: Even if this is the case, the OP can choose the two points appropriately at positions 1/3 and 2/3 or whatever before drawing the first bezier curve, then use them in drawing the thick portion. Using decoration will not be an easy task!